# Can't install the Shiny package

Tags: r, shiny

I can't install the Shiny package because of the sourcetools dependency. It seems I lack this: compilation of C/C++/Fortran
I am on a mac 10.7.5 and Rstudio version 1.0.44 and I don't know how to install a compiler.

I tried installing in a classic fashion
install.packages("shiny")
also installing the dependency ‘sourcetools’

Une version binaire est disponible mais la version du source est plus
  récente:
      binary source needs_compilation
shiny 0.13.2 0.14.2             FALSE

Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘sourcetools’
  These will not be installed
installing the source package ‘shiny’

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 38 2146k   38  831k    0     0  1004k      0  0:00:02 --:--:--  0:00:02 1022k100 2146k  100 2146k    0     0  1484k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1501k
ERROR: dependency ‘sourcetools’ is not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status

I tried installing from the Cran file
install.packages("~/Desktop/shiny_0.14.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
ERROR: dependency ‘sourcetools’ is not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/shiny’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/benoitkoenig/Desktop/shiny_0.14.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I tried installing from the URL 
install.packages('shiny', repo='http://nbcgib.uesc.br/mirrors/cran/')
Error in install.packages : La ligne commençant par '

I also tried to first install sourcetools seperately but I have the same problem.

Comment: If you want to compile from source you need to have the correct version of XCode for your version of OSX. There are only Mavericks fork versions of those packages on CRAN so you will need to get XCode and learn how to compile from source. OSX 10.7.x is _really_ old.

Comment: Another option might be to roll back to an earlier version of shiny. The dependency on `sourcetools is fairly recent. I didn't have sourcetools installed until I updated to 0.14.2.